# Hide magento default configurable option and create own

Tags: magento

I want to hide default magento 1.9 configurable option selection on product page and create my own for selection of product Like Size, Colour etc.
How i can do this in magenot 1.9

Comment: why not use attributes? and what have you tried before asking SO?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the default template for your configurable options with the following addition to `/app/design/frontend/[your]/[theme]/layout/local.xml`:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <reference name="product.info.options.configurable">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>path/to/your/template.phtml</template></action>
    <reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

I would recommend starting with a copy of `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` for reference, so you can see the code to pull relevant data.

Otherwise, you can customize your code in `app/design/frontend/[your]/[theme]/template/path/to/your/file.phtml` 'til your heart's content!

Comment: it will show an error "Please select an option..... " like this and product is not added to cart.

Comment: @Divyarajsinh - If you start with a copy of the original template (and it was not previously showing errors) then it will not show an error.  So, either you have not copied the file as I explained, or it was already showing an error.